# getting value from same class with AJAX/jQuery

Tags: jquery

How Can I get value from same class?
It just get the value from one class (the first)

look the code:

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.getdata').click(function() {
        var name  = $('.name').val();
        var userid = $('.userid').val();
        console.log(name);
        console.log(userid);
        var dataString = 'userid=' + name + '&name=' + name;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
            }
        }); 
        return false;
    });
});
```

this is in a loop

```html
<form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' class='name' value='".$row["name"]."' />
    <input type='hidden' class='userid' value='".$row["userid"]."' />
    <button type='submit' class='getdata'></button>
</form>
```

Comment: post the html with the `getdata` class

Comment: done, I edited the post

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to use the common parent element to associate each class with the clicked button.  You would update your click handler like so:

```
$('.getdata').click(function() {
    var name  = $(this).parent().find('.name').val();
    var userid = $(this).parent().find('.userid').val();
    console.log(name);
    console.log(userid);
    var dataString = 'userid=' + name + '&name=' + name;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
        }
    }); 
    return false;
});
```

Note, you could also achieve your goal via the `siblings()` method.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are passing all the data from the form and using jquery already, a common way to do it is to use jQuery's serialize() the data from the form.  Instead of putting your handler on the submit button, put it on the form...

```
<form action='' method='POST' id='myForm' >
    <input type='hidden' class='name' value='".$row["name"]."' />
    <input type='hidden' class='userid' value='".$row["userid"]."' />
    <button type='submit' class='getdata'></button>
</form>



$('#myForm').on('submit', function( event ) {

  var formData = $(this).serialize();

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
        }
    }); 

  // if you are doing ajax, you don't want to submit the 
  // form and reload the page also.  so you need to add the
  // event to the handler, and call
  // event.preventDefault();
  event.preventDefault();
});
```